# IE 9 and 8 Phorum/Wordpress template broken

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, forum

Need an IE master to help me figure out why this site is working in all browsers except for IE (v10 it looks fine, but 9 and  8 broken). www.askanewyorker.com/phorum

It's the Phorum lightweight template, where I've called WP load files and then called WP functions: header, footer, sidebar. I almost wonder if it's not some sort of header conflict, filetype, or something along those lines. css3 media queries.js and html5.js loaded but not fixing Phorum section of the site.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem was that I called the WP get header function in the header template file. I moved that into the core php files and that fixed it. I'll just have to make sure I put the code back in when I update Phorum since it's no longer isolated in the template.